# How To Use Business Intelligence Development Studio On Remote SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, data-migration, bids

Is that possible for BIDS to build a SSIS package on remote SQL Server instance? Since I only have SQL Server Standard Edition on the production server.

BTW, when I use BIDS to build a Integration Service Connection Project, it throws a exception like this:
exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown
And nothing is created. Anyone have ideas on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install SSIS on the client.

Comment: So the client still need license for Standard/Enterprise/Develop Edition?

Comment: You can develop with the Developer version, but to deploy with proper licensing, you'll need Enterprise.

Comment: You might find this thread useful (or confusing).  Apparently there are some situations where you can use standard.  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-SG/sqlintegrationservices/thread/6ce7599a-930d-47a9-8fd6-358bf9ed9ef2